# Multiple mysql threads getting opened on eloquent call?

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, laravel, eloquent

I am having a very odd issue in mysql today. I have laravel 4.2 install and I use eloquent for all my sql calls, I am running into an issue where I open 10 tabs on my website, and mysql opens more than 32 threads. I am running show stats in mysql to view threads_connected and normally it sits around 1-2, which makes sense to me is it seems like it has 2 active current connections to the database, meaning they are actively getting information. Any idea on what is going on? To compound this issue my site is using an amazon RDS micro instance which has a max number of connections of 32, so I open 10 or so tabs and no one can use my site and I get the "Too many connections" error.

Comment: Each page request will use it's own connection to the database, however they should be released automatically when the request is complete, unless you've hit a fatal error in which case the connection may be left open. If you have AJAX polling happening then each request will also use a db connection.

Comment: Interesting, is there a way in php to print or log active connections made by that page? I am wondering if I could pinpoint what is going on. Because it seems to happen on any page that has a mysql request, and none of them have errors.

Comment: eloquent should be smart enough to only make one db connection per page request, unless you've created multiple connections. review your **app/config/database.php** file to see if that's the case.